# TextWatcher (onTextChanged method)

Tags: android

I have a question about TextWatcher.I have a editbox (input type is phone)

What i want to do: when the app is opened, a format is shown in edittext like this.

http://hizliresim.com/vnDXp4

and when the user enters numbers,under-bar should be deleted automatically.

When i run the my project,i can show the format in the picture thanks to "before" "variable  but how to use onTextChanged method for this process.Do you have any idea?

My code:

```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.text.Editable;
  import android.text.TextWatcher;
  import android.widget.EditText;

  import java.lang.reflect.Array;
  import java.util.Arrays;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   EditText edittext1;
   String before ="_ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edittext1.setText(before);
   edittext1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


}

TextWatcher textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        //char single=0;
     String character=edittext1.getText().toString();
        //System.out.println(character);
            delete();


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }
};

public void delete()
{
    for(int i=0; i<=before.length(); i=i +2)
    {
        before.substring(i);

    }

}
```

}

my xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">




<EditText
    android:layout_width="350sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:maxLength="24"
     />
```

Comment: you can add hint to your text view so when you type hint will be gone.
like this: add it to textview
android:hint="phone_number"

Answer (score 0):

you can add hint to your text view so when you type hint will be gone. like this: add it to textview android:hint="phone_number"

Comment: so hint does't display?

Comment: when i enter the number,underline should be deleted son do i have to onTextChanged?

Comment: there is no textview ,i am sorry for the first post

Comment: you want to delete underline one by one when entering text?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: i dont think you can approach this by single edit text. you should use individual edit text per latter and use hint there.